# Setting the name of a machine

Tags: networking, server, samba, hostname

I've built a machine with spare parts with the intention of using it like a home server, but it does something I didn't expect, it adds ".local" to the hostname, so I can't access to it with the name I want, "servidor3". It only answers to "servidor3.local". I'm at loss of why it's happening.

Output from some commands, and files:

```
root@servidor3:# hostname
servidor3

root@servidor3:# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       servidor3

root@servidor3:# cat /etc/hostname
servidor3

samba.conf (edited)
[global]
  workgroup = HOMENET
  netbios name = servidor3
  server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
  wins support = yes
  local master = yes
  preferred master = yes
```

But from the windows clients:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Servidor>ping servidor3
In Spanish "Not found"

C:\Documents and Settings\Servidor>ping servidor3.local
Haciendo ping a servidor3.local [192.168.1.39] con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.39: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.39: bytes=32 tiempo=5ms TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.39: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=64
Respuesta desde 192.168.1.39: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=64
Estadísticas de ping para 192.168.1.39:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's called `avahi-daemon`. You can see it listening with `sudo lsof -i -n -P`.

Answer (score 0):

The .local TLD is a common shorthand for machines that live on a private network.  Your new server is behaving correctly, but you haven't configured your private network to accept that behaviour!

You would do best by leaving .local in the server name, and adding .local  to the TCP/IP search domains on your various clients.  The easiest way would be by adding it to your DHCP server settings (presumably on your router), but you can also do it manually on each machine.  Here's instructions for a windows client:

https://superuser.com/questions/61827/how-can-i-add-a-search-domain-in-windows-7